# C++ Equivalent of C# Static Class

Tags: c++

So in C# when I wanted to make globally available functions/variables, I would make a static class...

```
// SomeClass.cs
public static class SomeClass
{
    private static int bar;

    public static int Foo()
    {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

And if I wanted to do the same in C++, is this basically the same thing?

```
// SomeClass.h

class SomeClass
{
private:
    int bar;

public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();

    int foo();
};

extern SomeClass gSomeClass;
```

And in...

```
// SomeClass.cpp
#include "SomeClass.h"

SomeClass gSomeClass;

SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
    bar = 0;

    //....
}

SomeClass::~SomeClass()
{
    //....
}

int SomeClass::foo()
{
    return bar;
}
```

And in...

```
#include "SomeClass.h"

int main()
{
    return gSomeClass.foo();
    // (basically)
}
```

Would there be any problems with doing this?

Comment: You can create a class having only `static` functions. But in c++ usually a namespace and plain functions are preferred.

Comment: C# does not allow free functions like C++ does.  Either don't use a class at all or declare the members *static*.  Don't use a constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to implement the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). There is much debate as to when this pattern should be used due to the general sentiment that "global variables are bad", but it has its legitimate use-cases in my opinion. The keyword "singleton" should be more than enough to allow you research various C++ implementations of the pattern and find many discussions on the pros and cons of using it.

Comment: Alternatively, as Hans Passant pointed out in his comment, you can use free functions without a class wrapper, or private the constructor as Vlad suggested in his answer, if they are purely [functional functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) which aren't storing some static object state.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need a free function. These functions are not implemented in a class, usually they are preferred to be implemented in a namespace.

The status variable can be implemented in an anonymous namespace or as an extern of some sort. A function local static could also be used.

This will vary on how you wish to expose the data associated with the variable, the extern seems most likely in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This class is analogous to your C#:

```
// SomeClass.h
class SomeClass
{
private:
    static int bar;
    SomeClass(); // not to be instantiated

public:

    static int foo() { return bar; };
};
```

You can use it like that:

```
int x = SomeClass::foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is generally how you could do it:

SomeClass.h

```
    class SomeClass
    {
        static int bar;

        public:
        static int Foo()
        {
            return bar;
        }
    };
```

SomeClass.cpp

```
    #include "SomeClass.h"

    int SomeClass::bar = 0;
```

This has not been a common pattern in my experience though. Free functions tend to be preferable. Variables and functions don't have to be members of a class in sane languages like C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think an equivalent will look like:

```
class MyTest
{
public:
    static void Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    }
};

MyTest::Test();
```